# Как максимально плотно упаковать коробки в ящик?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть ящик у которого есть длина, высота, ширина, и есть коробки с такими же параметрами. Коробки разных размеров, но могут встречаться одинаковые. Необходимо упаковать коробки в ящик, чтобы влезло как можно больше. Как подойти к решению этой задачи? Есть какой-нибудь алгоритм? Может кто-то писал что-то подобное на JS?

Comment: это обычная комбинаторная задача. Решается либо тупо перебором, или с помощью теории графов.

Comment: [Задача о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Comment: Напишите постановку задачи, возможно ради интереса кто-то захочет помочь

Comment: Никакого отношения к "задаче о рюкзаке" эта задача не имеет даже отдаленно. (Что за чушь?) И "комбинаторной" ее можно назвать только в том смысле, в котором вообще все задачи являются "комбинаторными". Это классическая задача Трехмерного Раскроя И Упаковки. Обычно тема фокусируется на 1D и 2D раскрое. Для 3D *точное* решение будет неподъемным. Только приближенные алгоритмы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563271/3d-bin-packing-algorithm